# How to respond/listen for action of google assitant

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I have a chat application and i like to do some action like user says "Send message to xxx" need to open chat window in side my application.

Is it possible to do ?

If its possible guide me in right path .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a two way to do

1.Use Api.ai 
2.Google action sdk

You can find more [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/components/)